# Delphi Component error 00000000 when overriding Create method

Tags: delphi

I created a component in Delphi, and I'm trying to override the create method, like this:

```
unit DefButton;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Forms;

type
  TDefButton = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation


constructor TDefButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage('test!');
end;


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Default Controls', [TDefButton]);
end;

end.
```

But when I run it shows the message "test" but then it throws this message:

[image]

Then it shows the message again, and then it throws this one:

[image]

Any ideas of what can it be? I tried googling but couldn't find an answer for this specific case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `inherited;` in your constructor, so it calls chain of constructors from ancestor classes down to TObject constructor.

Try this:

```
constructor TDefButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('test!');
end;
```